# How to integrate Zookeeper cluster with Hbase cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper

i created 3 hbase1.2.5 distributed mode clusters and 3 zookeeper3.4.10 clusters. they are working fine independently. but now i want to integrate those 6 computers together.

i am using ubuntu 16.04 and virtual box.

Comment: Are you asking how to use your existing zookeeper cluster to manage your state information for hbase?

Comment: Edit the `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` property to point at the other cluster

Comment: thank you @cricket_007. i did it accordingly. but now how would i know that zookeeper is running successfully on hbase clusters? how to test those all? in my hbase clusters nodes are running as follows. at mastervm it shows jps, namenode, resourcemanager and hregionserver are running. at slave1 it shows jps, secondarynamenode, datanode, hregionserver, nodemanager are running well, then at slave2 it shows jps, namenode, hmaster, hregionserver, nodemanager, datanode, secondarynamenode are running. lastly at zookeeper servers it shows jps and jps and quorumpeermain.

Comment: yes @PaulBack i somehow managed to set those settings. but how would i  check zookeeper is working or not on hbase?

Answer (score 0):

Steps are as follows.

Set the following in hbase-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>zkhost1.example.com,zkhost2.example.com,zkhost3.example.com</value>
</property>
```

Set the following in hbase-env.sh:

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

Ensure that your hbase hosts can talk to the zookeeper hosts on port 2181, or another port.  If you need to use a port other than 2181, set hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort in hbase-site.xml and clientPort in Zookeeper's zoo.cfg file to the alternate port.

Rolling restart your zookeeper cluster if you changed the port.  Rolling restart your hbase cluster, region servers first then master(s).

To verify that it is working correctly:

A) Hbase services will have started successfully.  If they can't talk to a zookeeper quorum, they won't start up.

B) On one of your zookeeper hosts, execute the following command:

```
cd /usr/lib/zookeeper/bin && ./zkCli.sh # or wherever your ZOOKEEPER_HOME is

ls /hbase
```

If you get an error in the zkCLI, it means that the hbase zk node was not properly created.